# Add empty space on right border of chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my chart. To make it more descriptive I want to add epmty spaces at right border.
I mean something like additional invisible values on x axis after the black arrow.
[image]

To show you what i mean let me post third-party chart with feature I need:
[image]

If it does matter how I built the chart this is a slice of my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.margins(x=0)
ax.plot(x, y, color="chocolate")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x[len(x) - 1]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
plt.xlabel('Самая свежая дата: ' + d)
plt.text(df["Date"].iloc[-1], df["Value"].iloc[-1], df["Value"].iloc[-1])
plt.title(title + '\n' + region)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.savefig(title + '.png', dpi=300, format='png')
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Use `set_xlim` and increase xmax value depending on how much empty space you need : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-date-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data we employed was coded using Apple data from Yahoo Finance. As mentioned in the comments, ax.set_xlim() is used to specify the number of years for the addition. As it is, it will show future years, so we will create a new x-axis label. Future years will be added as blank.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.margins(x=0)
ax.plot(df.index, df['Close'], color="chocolate")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
# d = datetime.datetime.strptime(df.index, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
d = df.index[-1].strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
plt.xlabel('Самая свежая дата: ' + d)
plt.text(df.index[-1], df["Close"].iloc[-1], df["Close"].iloc[-1])
# plt.title(title + '\n' + region)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
plt.grid(axis='both')

ax.set_xlim(df.index[0], mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2025,3,1)))
xlabels = [*range(2011,2022),'','','','',]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
plt.show()
# plt.savefig(title + '.png', dpi=300, format='png')
# plt.close(fig)

print(xlabels)
[2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, '', '', '', '']
```

[image]